# “SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” Error on mac

Tags: python, macos, pandas

I had  wanted to solve the [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] problem,
because i use mac and python 3,a lot of guys said i should run /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command

but after i run the certificates.command, i seemed not work, terminal told me a lot of errors

and the problem of [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] isn't solved, i suspect maybe certificates wasn't installed properly

but i check pip list, certifi is the newest type, who can help me?

terminal information is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call 
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

my original programs is:

```
import pandas as pd

states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
print(states)
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I have installed Python3.8.3 and frida-tools, and I think I just had met the same problem.

[Problem]
After I installed Python3.8.3 by double click the installer python**.pkg, when I tried 'pip install frida-tools", it went "command not found: pip". Then I tried "pip3.8 install frida-tools", it went "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: ***** error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>"

[How to solve]
Open finder, go to /applications/python */, double click the shell "Install Certificates.command"

[Result]
After that I have install frida-tools normally by "pip install frida-tools"

I hope this can help you.