# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error with python3 on macOS 10.15

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

`/usr/bin/python3` from Xcode/CLT on macOS 10.15 (DB6/PB5 at the moment, with Xcode 11 beta 6) fails with `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` for all HTTPS requests originating from PSL, e.g. from `urllib.request`:

```py
$ /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.apple.com/")'
...
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

How to solve this problem?

(I know the answer, will post shortly; just sharing it in case other people run into it.)

Comment: Btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261444/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-on-mac is somewhat related, but that's a third party installation (from god knows what channel), whereas this is about the official distribution provided by Apple.

Comment: I think that question is talking about installer provided by PSF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `/usr/bin/python3` (from either Xcode or CLT) fails to correctly locate the trust store in `/etc/ssl`, as we can see using `ssl.get_default_verify_paths()`:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())'
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/certs')
```

It's looking into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl`, which doesn't exist.

Knowing this, we can use the following hack:

```
$ sudo rsync -avzP /etc/ssl/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/
```

I've submitted a bug report to Apple (btw, just realized bugreport.apple.com is now gone, and I had to use the Feedback Assistant website). Open radar https://openradar.appspot.com/7111585 (that radar number is unfortunately wrong — since bugreport.apple.com is gone, I don't have a radar number anymore, only a feedback number `FB7111585`).

Comment: Before executing the `rsync` hack, I faced error saying `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/` does not exist.

At the end, I ran `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc` to create the `etc` directory (provided by @bheinz answer) before doing `rsync`, finally it worked.

Comment: Update: now they thought they fixed the issue, but they didn’t. Now `cafile` points to `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/cert.pem` but the entire `etc` folder doesn’t exist under the 3.7 folder, so they still fail to resolve the correct certificate.

Comment: Update: Apple’s attitude is “use Requests instead”.

Answer (score 27):

Supplemental to @4ae1e1's answer, you can create a symlink to the SSL folder instead of rsyncing it. This will give the added benefit of keeping any changes in `/etc/ssl` up-to-date at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/`.

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/ln -s /etc/ssl/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/
```

Should do it.

Comment: Use `-p` with `mkdir`if it says "No such file or directory".

Comment: In my case, `xcode-select -p` shows `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` so I thought to try `sudo mkdir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/etc` and `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/etc/` but as @4ae1e1 says below, that's irrelevant because `python3 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())'` doesn't care

Comment: What worked for me: `sudo mkdir -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc` and `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/` then I needed an extra `sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/2216#issuecomment-527114519), Apple refused to fix this:

> The problem behaves as intended.
>
> `certifi` is a third-party module, not part of Python itself.
>
> `urllib` is a low-level library. It can handle SSL, but you must explicitly set up the SSL context with a `cafile`.
>
> Try the following instead:
>
> ```sh
> pip3 install requests
> python3 -c 'import requests; print(requests.get("https://apple.com").text)'
> ```
>
> If you only want to get `cacert.pem`, you can use `pip3 install certifi`, but you must still explicitly pass `cafile` to `urllib`.

So my solution is simply using Requests instead. This is supported and future proof.

Answer (score 2):

You should reinstall Xcode command line tools that contains Python.

```sh
pip3 uninstall -y -r <(pip requests certifi)
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3

sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -r

python3 -m pip install --user certifi
python3 -m pip install --user requests
```

Comment: when i ran first line it says that pip command not found
how can i solve this?

Comment: This means that you do not have pip3 and pip3 packages installed. Therefore you can skip this step. Xcode command line tools contains pip3.

Comment: I get an **"ERROR: unknown command "requests"**

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you ended up here because you were having this problem with a python installation that was done through homebrew using pyenv, then here's what I had to do to fix this thing.

*Specifically, I had the issue because I had previously tried to install python 3.6 on an m1 mac using these instructions: [Install python 3.6.* on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862398/install-python-3-6-on-mac-m1)*

1. Uninstall the x86 version of homebrew if you have it:

```
arch -x86 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

2. Save your homebrew configuration using [brew bundle](https://tomlankhorst.nl/brew-bundle-restore-backup/)
3. Uninstall m1 architecture homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

4. Clean up any lingering files from 1 and 3 that the uninstall script tells you about
5. Re-install homebrew ([see the site](https://brew.sh/)) and restore your  homebrew configuration using [brew bundle](https://tomlankhorst.nl/brew-bundle-restore-backup/)
6. Delete all python versions you have via pyenv (this could also be step 1 but I did it here)
7. Re-download the versions you want with pyenv
8. You're saved! Hopefully.

Answer (score -1):

i had an issue with 'abort 6' when importing 'requests' package after updating to catalina. while searching for a solution, i was lead to this page. unfortunately none of the above worked for me, however...

updating to python 3.8 manually from python.org seemed to solve this issue very easily for me. i had to reinstall all my packages (w/ pip3) as i came across errors, but that wasn't so bad.

i don't see any of my projects having an issue with python3.8 so far (been using 3.7 for a while)

hope this helps someone!
thanks for all the additional suggestions and efforts!

Answer (score -3):

`python3.6 -c 'import requests; requests.get("https://www.apple.com/")'`

Try using this.
Check if this works for you.