# How to fix ssl error for Python2/3 in macOs

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, https, python-requests, openssl

I am getting ssl error for all the urls using python requests method.

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)
```

Tried with both python2.7 & python 3.9, tried Install certificates.cmd. Curl for the same url is working. Tried with `brew install python3` 
curl response:

```
$ curl -v "https://mail.google.com"
*   Trying 216.58.199.165...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mail.google.com (216.58.199.165) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.mail.google.com
*  start date: Sep 16 04:07:17 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 16 04:07:17 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mail.google.com" matched cert's "mail.google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=CA; L=mountain view; O=xyz; OU=xyz; CN=xyz; emailAddress=xyz
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: mail.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
```

Python:
(Edit) request code:

```
python3 -c "import requests; requests.get('https://mail.google.com')"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mail.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mail.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

openssl versions:

```
$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
```

Comment: Are you in an environment that inspects network data? When I connect to that server, as for other google systems, I get a cert with issuer /C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1, and so does sslshopper. No xxx, no mountain view, and no emailAddress, and no root/selfsigned in the chain sent. Try `openssl s_client -connect mail.google.com:443 -showcerts` (1.1.1 no longer needs `-servername` for SNI) to see the chain sent, and identify what root it is using (or trying to) and see whether that is standard.

Comment: Thankyou for this @dave_thompson_085, it was the issue of network client, openssl is taking that client's ssl certificate while curl is taking the system's ssl. After disconnection from the client, everything started working.

Comment: You should reinstall Xcode command line tools that contains Python. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247505/4067700