# macOS pyenv: pip install not working [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, macos, ssl, openssl, pyenv

I am trying to install numpy package using pip while working with pyenv (global version 3.8.6).

Command:

```
pip install numpy
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

What I tried to fix this issue:

- Reinstalling openssl using `brew reinstall openssl`
- Reinstalling pyenv using `brew reinstall pyenv`
- Reinstalling pyenv-virtualenv using `brew reinstall pyenv-virtualenv`

When I try to disable pyenv by removing `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` and `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` from the `~/.bash_profile`, it works fine as it uses the system Python version.

A short term solution is to add `--trusted-host pypi.org` flag, but I am not sure why it is not working without the flag.

Please help!

Comment: I am using MacOs BigSur and pyenv is not working fine. later found new version of mac is not updating the openssl anymore. So, I used brew to install openssl@1.1. configured path, pkgconfig, cnames and all. Now I can run applications but unable to install any package via private nexus repository. Also, unable to verify ssl certs for wss client like paho-mqtt. This looks like issue with openssl in my MacOs. Still figuring out...

Comment: You should reinstall Xcode command line tools that contains Python. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247505/4067700

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue28150), in previous versions of Python, Apple provided the OpenSSL packages, but they no longer do.

For a temporary fix, add pypi.org as a trusted host (pythonhosted.org actually hosts the files, but they are downloaded from pypi hence why they are also added to the trusted hosts) when using pip:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools
```

For a more permanent fix install certifi and Scrapy:

```
pip install certifi
pip install Scrapy
```

[Similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) 
[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509902/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-using-pip-to-install-packages/49910594)

Comment: This is not useful, my question is more on why I am getting an SSL error when I am trying not to put --trusted-host. It works fine with --trusted-host flag as I mentioned above.

Comment: @HimanshuMalhotra I have updated myanswer to explain why this problem occurs and why you have to put the flag.