# Problems installing python 3.6.9 with pyenv on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I am trying to install python version 3.6.9 in a python virtual environment.

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482346/problems-installing-python-3-6-with-pyenv-on-mac-os-big-sur). Following it I run (NOTE: I changed the version to 3.6.9

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.9 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

And I get this error

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.9.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.9...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/macOS/2020-06-24-13-51-57.bpo-41100.mcHdc5.rst
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 3375 (offset -51 lines).
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 495 (offset -15 lines).
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.5 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/ny/t4jdkmvd2ydfgp0w21w6nxbw0000gn/T/python-build.20220809113814.44789
Results logged to /var/folders/ny/t4jdkmvd2ydfgp0w21w6nxbw0000gn/T/python-build.20220809113814.44789.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Then tried following this error:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.5 using python-build 20180424)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/ny/t4jdkmvd2ydfgp0w21w6nxbw0000gn/T/python-build.20220809111200.38273
```

For which I did `sudo rm -rf /LibraryDeveloper/CommandLineTools` and `xcode-select —install`. Then running `pyenv install 3.6.9` or the `CFLAGS` from above, I still run into the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install python 3.6.\* on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862398/install-python-3-6-on-mac-m1)