# Unable to Install python 3.6.8 using pyenv on mac Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: macos, python-3.6, pyenv, macos-monterey

I'm trying to install python 3.6.8 using pyenv on mac Monterey 12.5.1 but encountering below error

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Installing Python-3.6.8...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/macOS/2020-06-24-13-51-57.bpo-41100.mcHdc5.rst
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 3375 (offset -51 lines).
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 495 (offset -15 lines).
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.5.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7h/p55vm3356_jg4jns3n8vngzm0000gp/T/python-build.20220823112323.4068
Results logged to /var/folders/7h/p55vm3356_jg4jns3n8vngzm0000gp/T/python-build.20220823112323.4068.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I have tried to reinstall pyenv but it does not help

I have also tried

````
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"

LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib"

pyenv install --patch 3.6.8 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and doing installation by steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862398/install-python-3-6-on-mac-m1/71957981#71957981) helped me. Before following these steps, you better to uninstall all python versions you currently have and pyenv, homebrew.