# Issue installing python 3.6.8 on Mac M1

Tags: python, macos, python-3.6, apple-m1, python-install

I'm trying to run an old app that requires python =3.6.8 on Mac M1 machine with Monterey OS X 12.6.1.

I've installed pyenv-virtualenv and pyenv and successfully installed python 3.6.15. However, when I try to install 3.6.8, I'm getting error -

```
~ % pyenv86 install --patch 3.6.8 <<(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv/master/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/patches/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8/0008-bpo-45405-Prevent-internal-configure-error-when-runn.patch\?full_index\=1)
Error: No available formula with the name "openssl@1.0". Did you mean openssl@1.1 or openssl@3?
Downloading openssl-1.1.0j.tar.gz...
-> https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.0/openssl-1.1.0j.tar.gz
Installing openssl-1.1.0j...
Installed openssl-1.1.0j to /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8

python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.8...
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.6.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735
Results logged to /var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735.log

Last 10 log lines:
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_get_ext.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_get_ext_by_NID.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_get_ext_by_OBJ.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_get_ext_by_critical.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_delete_ext.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509_REVOKED_add_ext.html -> /Users/lokesh.raizada/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/openssl/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/X509v3_get_ext_by_NID.html
/var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735 ~
~
/var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735 ~
/var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735/Python-3.6.8 /var/folders/41/4c6czpkx6c18sfcfj0lzjkd00000gq/T/python-build.20230127152902.5735
```

I have found this link which installs 3.6.15 with a patch. Is there any patch associated with 3.6.8 as well ?
[Install python 3.6.* on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862398/install-python-3-6-on-mac-m1/71957981#71957981)

I tried the same for 3.6.8 but no luck -

```
~ % pyenv86 install --patch 3.6.8 <<(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv/master/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/patches/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8/0008-bpo-45405-Prevent-internal-configure-error-when-runn.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling all python modules, python version, pyenv, XCode commandtools as well.

Do not use pyenv, as pyenv support is not available below 3.6.15 -
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1737#issuecomment-1423110250

Then proceed to Install 3.6.8 from - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-macosx10.9.pkg